# Grid layout empty lines to be visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a grid layout of images that at some point disappear from the grid. The problem is that when a whole row/column disappear the following ones take its position.

For example if i have a table of 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
and remove the 4s, the 5s will take their position.

I need to leave the column/row space empty.

(I wasn't sure what title to write.)

```
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="7"
            android:rowCount="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="6">

            <Button
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_3"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_4"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>


            <Button
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_5"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="6"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_6"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="7"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_7"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:text="8"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_8"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="9"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_9"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="10"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_10"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="11"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_11"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="12"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_12"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="13"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_13"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="14"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_14"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="15"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_15"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="16"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_16"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="17"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_17"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="18"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_18"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="19"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_19"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="20"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_20"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="21"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_21"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="22"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_22"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="23"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_23"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="24"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_24"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="25"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_25"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

            <Button
                android:text="26"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/briefcase"
                android:id="@+id/box_26"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:onClick="box_onClick" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: First, where are the images that disappear? I only see buttons with text in the layout. Second (and more important), how are the images disappearing from the grid? Are you removing them from the layout? Setting visibility? Please show us the code.

Comment: @TedHopp I should have said that the buttons have a background image and that they are not actually images. I remove the images/buttons with setVisibility(View.Gone). Isaac actually already gave me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making the buttons disappear by using `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, try using `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` instead.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) for more

Comment: Didn't know about View.Invisible. Thanks.